# Docker Swarm Mode: Not all VIPs for a service work. Getting timeouts for several VIPs

Tags: networking, docker, docker-swarm

**Description**
I'm having issues with an overlay network using docker swarm mode (IMPORTANT: swarm mode, not swarm). I have an overlay network named "internal". I have a service named "datacollector" that is scaled to 12 instances. I `docker exec` into another service running in the same swarm (and on the same overlay network) and run `curl http://datacollector` 12 times. However, 4 of the requests result in a timeout. I then run `dig tasks.datacollector` and get a list of 12 ip addresses. Sure enough, 8 of the ip addresses work but 4 timeout every time.

I tried scaling the service down to 1 instance and then back up to 12, but got the same result.

I then used `docker service ps datacollector` to find each running instance of my service. I used `docker kill xxxx` on each node to manually kill all instances and let the swarm recreate them. I then checked dig again and verified that the list of IP addresses for the task was no longer the same. After this I ran `curl http://datacollector` 12 more times. Now only 3 requests work and the remaining 9 timeout!

This is the second time this has happened in the last 2 weeks or so. The previous time I had to remove all services, remove the overlay network, recreate the overlay network, and re-create all of the services in order to resolve the issue. Obviously, this isn't a workable long term solution :(

**Output of `docker service inspect datacollector:**

```
[
    {
        "ID": "2uevc4ouakk6k3dirhgqxexz9",
        "Version": {
            "Index": 72152
        },
        "CreatedAt": "2016-11-12T20:38:51.137043037Z",
        "UpdatedAt": "2016-11-17T15:22:34.402801678Z",
        "Spec": {
            "Name": "datacollector",
            "TaskTemplate": {
                "ContainerSpec": {
                    "Image": "507452836298.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/swarm/api:61d7931f583742cca91b368bc6d9e15314545093",
                    "Args": [
                        "node",
                        ".",
                        "api/dataCollector"
                    ],
                    "Env": [
                        "ENVIRONMENT=stage",
                        "MONGODB_URI=mongodb://mongodb:27017/liveearth",
                        "RABBITMQ_URL=amqp://rabbitmq",
                        "ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch"
                    ]
                },
                "Resources": {
                    "Limits": {},
                    "Reservations": {}
                },
                "RestartPolicy": {
                    "Condition": "any",
                    "MaxAttempts": 0
                },
                "Placement": {
                    "Constraints": [
                        "node.labels.role.api==true",
                        "node.labels.role.api==true",
                        "node.labels.role.api==true",
                        "node.labels.role.api==true",
                        "node.labels.role.api==true"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "Mode": {
                "Replicated": {
                    "Replicas": 12
                }
            },
            "UpdateConfig": {
                "Parallelism": 1,
                "FailureAction": "pause"
            },
            "Networks": [
                {
                    "Target": "88e9fd9715o5v1hqu6dnkg3vp"
                }
            ],
            "EndpointSpec": {
                "Mode": "vip"
            }
        },
        "Endpoint": {
            "Spec": {
                "Mode": "vip"
            },
            "VirtualIPs": [
                {
                    "NetworkID": "88e9fd9715o5v1hqu6dnkg3vp",
                    "Addr": "192.168.1.23/24"
                }
            ]
        },
        "UpdateStatus": {
            "State": "completed",
            "StartedAt": "2016-11-17T15:19:34.471292948Z",
            "CompletedAt": "2016-11-17T15:22:34.402794312Z",
            "Message": "update completed"
        }
    }
]
```

**Output of `docker network inspect internal`:**

```
[
    {
        "Name": "internal",
        "Id": "88e9fd9715o5v1hqu6dnkg3vp",
        "Scope": "swarm",
        "Driver": "overlay",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "192.168.1.0/24",
                    "Gateway": "192.168.1.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Containers": {
            "03ac1e71139ff2140f93c80d9e6b1d69abf442a0c2362610bee3e116e84ef434": {
                "Name": "datacollector.5.cxmvk7p1hwznautresir94m3s",
                "EndpointID": "22445be80ba55b67d7cfcfbc75f2c15586bace5f317be8ba9b59c5f9f338525c",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:01:72",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.1.114/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "08ae84c7cb6e57583baf12c2a9082c1d17f1e65261cfa93346aaa9bda1244875": {
                "Name": "auth.10.aasw00k7teq4knxibctlrrj7e",
                "EndpointID": "c3506c851f4c9f0d06d684a9f023e7ba529d0149d70fa7834180a87ad733c678",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:01:44",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.1.68/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "192203a127d6831c3f4a41eabdd8df5282e33c3e92b99c3baaf1f213042f5418": {
                "Name": "parkingcollector.1.8yrm6d831wrfsrkzhal7cf2pm",
                "EndpointID": "34de6e9621ef54f7d963db942a7a7b6e0013ac6db6c9f17b384de689b1f1b187",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:01:9a",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.1.154/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "24258109e16c1a5b15dcc84a41d99a4a6617bcadecc9b35279c721c0d2855141": {
                "Name": "stream.8.38npsusmpa1pf8fbnmaux57rx",
                "EndpointID": "b675991ffbd5c0d051a4b68790a33307b03b48582fd1b37ba531cf5e964af0ce",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:01:74",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.1.116/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "33063b988473b73be2cbc51e912e165112de3d01bc00ee2107aa635e30a36335": {
                "Name": "billing.2.ca41k2h44zkn9wfbsif0lfupf",
                "EndpointID": "77c576929d5e82f1075b4cc6fcb4128ce959281d4b9c1c22d9dcd1e42eed8b5e",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:01:87",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.1.135/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "8b0929e66e6c284206ea713f7c92f1207244667d3ff02815d4bab617c349b220": {
                "Name": "shotspottercollector.2.328408tiyy8aryr0g1ipmm5xm",
                "EndpointID": "f2a0558ec67745f5d1601375c2090f5cd141303bf0d54bec717e3463f26ed74d",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:01:90",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.1.144/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "938fe5f6f9bb893862e8c06becd76c1a7fe5f2d3b791fc55d7d8164e67ee3553": {
                "Name": "inrixproxy.2.ed77crvat0waw41phjknhhm6v",
                "EndpointID": "88f550fecd60f0bdb0dfc9d5bf0c74716a91d009bcc27dc4392b113ab1215038",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:01:96",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.1.150/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "970f9d4c6ae6cc4de54a1d501408720b7d95114c28a6615d8e4e650b7e69bc40": {
                "Name": "rabbitmq.1.e7j721g6hfhs8r7p3phih4g9v",
                "EndpointID": "c04a4a5650ee6e10b87884004aa2cb1ec6b1c7036af15c31579462b6621436a2",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:01:1e",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.1.30/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "b1f676e6d38eec026583943dc0abff1163d21e6be9c5901539c46288f8941638": {
                "Name": "logspout.0.51j8juw8aj0rjjccp2am0rib5",
                "EndpointID": "98a93153abd6897c58276340df2eeec5c0ceb77fbe17d1ce8c465febb06776c7",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:01:10",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.1.16/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "bab4d80be830fa3b3fefe501c66e3640907a2cbb2addc925a0eb6967a771a172": {
                "Name": "auth.2.8fduvrn5ayk024b0lkhyz50of",
                "EndpointID": "7e81d41fa04ec14263a2423d8ef003d6d431a8c3ff319963197f8a8d73b4e361",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:01:3a",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.1.58/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "bc3c75a7c2d8c078eb7cc1555833ff0d374d82045dd9fb24ccfc37868615bb5e": {
                "Name": "reverseproxy.6.2g20zphn5j1r2feylzcplyorg",
                "EndpointID": "6c2138966ebcd144b47229a94ee603d264f3954a96ccd024d9e96501b7ffd5c0",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:01:6c",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.1.108/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "cd59d61b16ac0325336121a8558e8215e42aa5300f75054df17a70bf1f3e6c0c": {
                "Name": "usgscollector.1.0h0afyw8va8maoa4tjd5qz588",
                "EndpointID": "952073efc6a567ebd3f80d26811222c675183e8c76005fbf12388725a97b1bee",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:01:48",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.1.72/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "d40476e56b91762b0609acd637a4f70e42c88d266f8ebb7d9511050a8fc1df17": {
                "Name": "kibana.1.6hxu5b97hfykuqr5yb9i9sn5r",
                "EndpointID": "08c5188076f9b8038d864d570e7084433a8d97d4c8809d27debf71cb5d652cd7",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:01:06",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.1.6/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "e29369ad8ee5b12fb0c6f9bcb899514ab092f7da291a7c05eea758b0c19bfb65": {
                "Name": "weatherbugcollector.1.crpub0hf85cewxm0qt6annsra",
                "EndpointID": "afa1ddbad8ab8fdab69505ddb5342ac89c0d17bc75a11e9ac0ac8829e5885997",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:01:2e",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.1.46/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "f1bf0a656ecb9d7ef9b837efa94a050d9c98586f7312435e48b9a129c5e92e46": {
                "Name": "socratacollector.1.627icslq6kdb4syaha6tzkb19",
                "EndpointID": "14bea0d9ec3f94b04b32f36b7172c60316ee703651d0d920126a49dd0fa99cf5",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:01:1b",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.1.27/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.driver.overlay.vxlanid_list": "257"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

**Output of `dig datacollector`:**

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-9+deb8u8-Debian <<>> datacollector
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 38227
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;datacollector.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
datacollector.      600 IN  A   192.168.1.23

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.11#53(127.0.0.11)
;; WHEN: Thu Nov 17 16:11:57 UTC 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 60
```

**Output of `dig tasks.datacollector`:**

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-9+deb8u8-Debian <<>> tasks.datacollector
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 9810
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 12, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;tasks.datacollector.       IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
tasks.datacollector.    600 IN  A   192.168.1.115
tasks.datacollector.    600 IN  A   192.168.1.66
tasks.datacollector.    600 IN  A   192.168.1.22
tasks.datacollector.    600 IN  A   192.168.1.114
tasks.datacollector.    600 IN  A   192.168.1.37
tasks.datacollector.    600 IN  A   192.168.1.139
tasks.datacollector.    600 IN  A   192.168.1.148
tasks.datacollector.    600 IN  A   192.168.1.110
tasks.datacollector.    600 IN  A   192.168.1.112
tasks.datacollector.    600 IN  A   192.168.1.100
tasks.datacollector.    600 IN  A   192.168.1.39
tasks.datacollector.    600 IN  A   192.168.1.106

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.11#53(127.0.0.11)
;; WHEN: Thu Nov 17 16:08:54 UTC 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 457
```

**Output of `docker version`:**

```
Client:
 Version:      1.12.3
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   6b644ec
 Built:        Wed Oct 26 23:26:11 2016
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.12.3
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   6b644ec
 Built:        Wed Oct 26 21:44:32 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

**Output of `docker info`:**

```
Containers: 58
 Running: 15
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 43
Images: 123
Server Version: 1.12.3
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 430
 Dirperm1 Supported: false
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: host null overlay bridge
Swarm: active
 NodeID: 8uxexr2uz3qpn5x1km9k4le9s
 Is Manager: true
 ClusterID: 2kd4md2qyu67szx4y6q2npnet
 Managers: 3
 Nodes: 8
 Orchestration:
  Task History Retention Limit: 5
 Raft:
  Snapshot Interval: 10000
  Heartbeat Tick: 1
  Election Tick: 3
 Dispatcher:
  Heartbeat Period: 5 seconds
 CA Configuration:
  Expiry Duration: 3 months
 Node Address: 10.10.44.201
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Security Options: apparmor
Kernel Version: 3.13.0-91-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 3.676 GiB
Name: stage-0
ID: 76Z2:GN43:RQND:BBAJ:AGUU:S3F7:JWBC:CCCK:I4VH:PKYC:UHQT:IR2U
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Username: herbrandson
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No swap limit support
Labels:
 provider=generic
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
```

**Additional environment details:**
Docker swarm mode (not swarm). All nodes are running on AWS. The swarm has 8 nodes (3 managers and 5 workers)

**UPDATE:**
Per the comments, here's a snipet from the docker daemon logs on the swarm master

```
time="2016-11-17T15:19:45.890158968Z" level=error msg="container status 
unavailable" error="context canceled" module=taskmanager task.id=ch6w74b3cu78y8r2ugkmfmu8a 
time="2016-11-17T15:19:48.929507277Z" level=error msg="container status unavailable" error="context canceled" module=taskmanager task.id=exb6dfc067nxudzr8uo1eyj4e 
time="2016-11-17T15:19:50.104962867Z" level=error msg="container status unavailable" error="context canceled" module=taskmanager task.id=6mbbfkilj9gslfi33w7sursb9 
time="2016-11-17T15:19:50.877223204Z" level=error msg="container status unavailable" error="context canceled" module=taskmanager task.id=drd8o0yn1cg5t3k76frxgukaq 
time="2016-11-17T15:19:54.680427504Z" level=error msg="container status unavailable" error="context canceled" module=taskmanager task.id=9lwl5v0f2v6p52shg6gixs3j7 
time="2016-11-17T15:19:54.949118806Z" level=error msg="container status unavailable" error="context canceled" module=taskmanager task.id=51q1eeilfspsm4cx79nfkl4r0 
time="2016-11-17T15:19:56.485909146Z" level=error msg="container status unavailable" error="context canceled" module=taskmanager task.id=3vjzfjjdrjio2gx45q9c3j6qd 
time="2016-11-17T15:19:56.934070026Z" level=error msg="Error closing logger: invalid argument" 
time="2016-11-17T15:20:00.000614497Z" level=error msg="Error closing logger: invalid argument" 
time="2016-11-17T15:20:00.163458802Z" level=error msg="container status unavailable" error="context canceled" module=taskmanager task.id=4xa2ub5npxyxpyx3vd5n1gsuy 
time="2016-11-17T15:20:01.463407652Z" level=error msg="Error closing logger: invalid argument" 
time="2016-11-17T15:20:01.949087337Z" level=error msg="Error closing logger: invalid argument" 
time="2016-11-17T15:20:02.942094926Z" level=error msg="Failed to create real server 192.168.1.150 for vip 192.168.1.32 fwmark 947 in sb 938fe5f6f9bb893862e8c06becd76c1a7fe5f2d3b791fc55d7d8164e67ee3553: no such process" 
time="2016-11-17T15:20:03.319168359Z" level=error msg="Failed to delete a new service for vip 192.168.1.61 fwmark 2133: no such process" 
time="2016-11-17T15:20:03.363775880Z" level=error msg="Failed to add firewall mark rule in sbox /var/run/docker/netns/5de57ee133a5: reexec failed: exit status 5" 
time="2016-11-17T15:20:05.772683092Z" level=error msg="Error closing logger: invalid argument" 
time="2016-11-17T15:20:06.059212643Z" level=error msg="Error closing logger: invalid argument" 
time="2016-11-17T15:20:07.335686642Z" level=error msg="Failed to delete a new service for vip 192.168.1.67 fwmark 2134: no such process" 
time="2016-11-17T15:20:07.385135664Z" level=error msg="Failed to add firewall mark rule in sbox /var/run/docker/netns/6699e7c03bbd: reexec failed: exit status 5" 
time="2016-11-17T15:20:07.604064777Z" level=error msg="Error closing logger: invalid argument" 
time="2016-11-17T15:20:07.673852364Z" level=error msg="Failed to delete a new service for vip 192.168.1.75 fwmark 2097: no such process" 
time="2016-11-17T15:20:07.766525370Z" level=error msg="Failed to add firewall mark rule in sbox /var/run/docker/netns/6699e7c03bbd: reexec failed: exit status 5" 
time="2016-11-17T15:20:09.080101131Z" level=error msg="Failed to create real server 192.168.1.155 for vip 192.168.1.35 fwmark 904 in sb 192203a127d6831c3f4a41eabdd8df5282e33c3e92b99c3baaf1f213042f5418: no such process" 
time="2016-11-17T15:20:11.516338629Z" level=error msg="Error closing logger: invalid argument" 
time="2016-11-17T15:20:11.729274237Z" level=error msg="Failed to delete a new service for vip 192.168.1.83 fwmark 2124: no such process" 
time="2016-11-17T15:20:11.887572806Z" level=error msg="Failed to add firewall mark rule in sbox /var/run/docker/netns/5b810132057e: reexec failed: exit status 5" 
time="2016-11-17T15:20:12.281481060Z" level=error msg="Failed to delete a new service for vip 192.168.1.73 fwmark 2136: no such process" 
time="2016-11-17T15:20:12.395326864Z" level=error msg="Failed to add firewall mark rule in sbox /var/run/docker/netns/5b810132057e: reexec failed: exit status 5" 
time="2016-11-17T15:20:20.263565036Z" level=error msg="Failed to create real server 192.168.1.72 for vip 192.168.1.91 fwmark 2163 in sb cd59d61b16ac0325336121a8558e8215e42aa5300f75054df17a70bf1f3e6c0c: no such process" 
time="2016-11-17T15:20:20.410996971Z" level=error msg="Failed to delete a new service for vip 192.168.1.95 fwmark 2144: no such process" 
time="2016-11-17T15:20:20.456710211Z" level=error msg="Failed to add firewall mark rule in sbox /var/run/docker/netns/88d38a2bfb77: reexec failed: exit status 5" 
time="2016-11-17T15:20:21.389253510Z" level=error msg="Failed to create real server 192.168.1.46 for vip 192.168.1.99 fwmark 2145 in sb cd59d61b16ac0325336121a8558e8215e42aa5300f75054df17a70bf1f3e6c0c: no such process" 
time="2016-11-17T15:20:22.208965378Z" level=error msg="Failed to create real server 192.168.1.46 for vip 192.168.1.99 fwmark 2145 in sb e29369ad8ee5b12fb0c6f9bcb899514ab092f7da291a7c05eea758b0c19bfb65: no such process" 
time="2016-11-17T15:20:23.334582312Z" level=error msg="Failed to create a new service for vip 192.168.1.97 fwmark 2166: file exists" 
time="2016-11-17T15:20:23.495873232Z" level=error msg="Failed to create real server 192.168.1.48 for vip 192.168.1.17 fwmark 552 in sb e29369ad8ee5b12fb0c6f9bcb899514ab092f7da291a7c05eea758b0c19bfb65: no such process" 
time="2016-11-17T15:20:25.831988014Z" level=error msg="Failed to create real server 192.168.1.116 for vip 192.168.1.41 fwmark 566 in sb 03ac1e71139ff2140f93c80d9e6b1d69abf442a0c2362610bee3e116e84ef434: no such process" 
time="2016-11-17T15:20:25.850904011Z" level=error msg="Failed to create real server 192.168.1.116 for vip 192.168.1.41 fwmark 566 in sb 03ac1e71139ff2140f93c80d9e6b1d69abf442a0c2362610bee3e116e84ef434: no such process" 
time="2016-11-17T15:20:37.159637665Z" level=error msg="container status unavailable" error="context canceled" module=taskmanager task.id=6yhu3glre4tbz6d08lk2pq9eb 
time="2016-11-17T15:20:48.229343512Z" level=error msg="Error closing logger: invalid argument" 
time="2016-11-17T15:51:16.027686909Z" level=error msg="Error getting service internal: service internal not found" 
time="2016-11-17T15:51:16.027708795Z" level=error msg="Handler for GET /v1.24/services/internal returned error: service internal not found" 
time="2016-11-17T16:15:50.946921655Z" level=error msg="container status unavailable" error="context canceled" module=taskmanager task.id=cxmvk7p1hwznautresir94m3s 
time="2016-11-17T16:16:01.994494784Z" level=error msg="Error closing logger: invalid argument"
```

**UPDATE 2:**
I tried removing the service and re-creating it and that did not resolve the issue.

**UPDATE 3:**
I went through and rebooted each node in the cluster one-by-one. After that things appear to be back to normal. However, I still don't know what caused this. More importantly, how do I keep this from happening again in the future?

Comment: Anything in the daemon logs?

Comment: @johnharris85 I've updated the question with logs from the swarm manager

Comment: I've posted this as a bug on dockers github page. https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/28564